# Regex: How to capture optional group in middle of text?

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with using regex to capture some optional text - it's in the middle of some filenames, but not all. The big problem appears to be that my optional group is not anchored (I am using `.*?` before and after it). I looked extensively through past answers on SO, but most of them were able to capture optional text only if it was anchored on one side or the other (ie. at the end of the line).

Given a list of filenames, there are up to 5 things I'm trying to capture:

- NAME: always present, 1st thing in filename
- NUMBER: always present, 2nd thing in filename (and may be in parentheses)
- SHAPE: always present
- COLOR: sometimes present, but can come before or after the shape
- VERSION: sometimes present, will always come last (but there will usually be junk text after it)

Source text:

```
name 1111 color shape
name 2222 shape color
name 3333 shape
name (4444) color shape version
name.5555.JUNK.color.JUNK.shape.JUNK.version.JUNK
```

Desired results:

```
name (1111) color shape
name (2222) color shape
name (3333) shape
name (4444) color shape version
name (5555) color shape version
```

But when I use this regex:

```
FIND: (.*?).\(?(\d{4}).*?(color)?.*?(shape).*?(color)?.*?(version)?.*
REPLACE: $1 ($2) $3$5 $4 $6
```

I get this:

```
name (1111)  shape
name (2222)  shape
name (3333)  shape
name (4444)  shape
name (5555)  shape
```

As you can see, by making the `(color)` and `(version)` capture groups optional, it's not picking them up at all. (Also, if there's any way to remove the extra whitespace, that would be great too.)

By the way, I'm using `.*?` in between each capture group because I learned it's the "lazy" version of `.*` (not "greedy") - basically, it tries to match as little as possible instead of as much as possible. More info on that here if you're a regex newbie like me: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap

Anyways, is there something really obvious I'm missing here? Or is there no way to capture some optional text via regex?

PS. Here's my data pre-loaded on an online tool to play with: http://regexr.com/3cs84 - I understand that regex can differ a little by langugage/platform, so if it makes any difference, I ultimately want to use this regex in an AppleScript for renaming files and folders (likely by invoking a terminal command since I don't think AppleScript natively supports regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the `.*?(foo)` parts in parentheses like `(.*?(foo))` so that the `?` operator will take the `.*?` parts into consideration.

Corrected syntax `(.*?).\(?(\d{4})(.*?(color))?.*?(shape)(.*?(color))?(.*?(version))?.*` ([example](http://regexr.com/3cs8j))

Comment: Oh snap, that worked! Thanks so much! For anyone else looking at this and wondering why the regexr.com results don't match up with my desired results, I just had to make one tweak to AlphaDelta's replace function: "$1 ($2) $4$7 $5 $9"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with the format you are trying to use, but I believe I came up with an example of something that tackles the problem you have.

http://regexr.com/3cs8g

```
/name ((\([0-9]+\))|([0-9]+)) ((color shape)|(shape( color)?))( version)?/ig
```

What your describing is an optional clause that can appear in one of two spots. So, you make an or statement to test for each possible spot.

Comment: It looks like that would work for most of my test cases, but not where I have some "junk" text in between the clauses. Definitely helps though, thanks!