# Replacing string with regex capture

Tags: regex

The question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593191/regex-how-to-capture-optional-group-in-middle-of-text).

input:

```
name 1111 color shape
name 2222 shape color
name 3333 shape
name (4444) color shape version
name.5555.JUNK.color.JUNK.shape.JUNK.version.JUNK
```

looking forward to:

```
name (1111) color shape
name (2222) color shape
name (3333) shape
name (4444) color shape version
name (5555) color shape version
```

I try:

```
(name).\(?(\d{4})\)?.(?=.*?(color))(?=.*(shape))(?=.*?(version)?).*?$
```

replace:$1 ($2) $3 $4 $5

```
name (1111) color shape 
name (2222) color shape 
name (4444) color shape 
name (5555) color shape
```

other

```
 (name).\(?(\d{4})\)?.(?=.*?(color))(?=.*(shape))(?=.*?(version)).*?$

name (4444) color shape version
name (5555) color shape version
```

How I improve my regex validate?
Thanks.

Comment: Replace look aheads with optional groups and adjust the patterns inside them accordingly.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "looking forward to"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind possibly having a few trailing spaces, this can be as simple as:

```
(name).\((\d{4})\)(?:.*?(color)(?:.*?(shape)(?:.*?(version))?)?)?
```

If you want it to be simpler and don't mind possibly wasting a lot more time evaluating:

```
(name).\((\d{4})\).*?(color)?.*?(shape)?.*?(version)?
```

For both of these, replacing with

```
$1 ($2) $3 $4 $5
```

will give you what you want, at least if I understood the question correctly.