# extract multiple id from a sentence to a variable

Tags: c#, string

I have the string as an input

```
The user with id '2156' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '1' with the quantity of '1'.
```

I want to get the `user id` and `item id` from the string.

Can I match the input string with the `const string` and get the id from the input?

```
public const string StashAcquired = 
@"The user with id '{0}' helped the user '{1}' to acquire an item with the id '{2}' with the quantity of '{3}'.";

 here: {0} is a `user id`
       {2} is a `item id`
```

I don't want the other number but only two id.

```
@"The user with id '{userid}' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '{itemid}' with the quantity of '1'.";
```

rest id are irrelevant for me:

I tried by getting the number from the input string and assign it into a variable like:

```
 const string input = @"The user with id '2156' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '1' with the quantity of '1'.";

 var number = GetNumbersFromString(input);
```

**GetNumbersFromString**

```
 public int[] GetNumbersFromString(string str)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    string[] numbers = Regex.Split(str, @"\D+");
    int i;

    foreach (string value in numbers)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(value, out i))
        {
            result.Add(i);
        }
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

**Edit**

I am gradually noticing that the inputs are more complex than what I have mentioned before, input are coming as:

```
[{
    "Component": "Stash",
    "EventName": "An Item Acquired",
    "Description": "The user with id '2156' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '1' with the quantity of '1'"
}, {
    "Component": "H5P",
    "EventName": "Course module viewed",
    "Description": "The user with id '2253' viewed the 'hvp' activity with course module id '277'."
}, {
    "Component": "System",
    "EventName": "Course module completion updated",
    "Description": "The user with id '2254' updated the completion state for the course module with id '347' for the user with id '2254'."
}, {
    "Component": "H5P",
    "EventName": "Course module viewed",
    "Description": "The user with id '2253' viewed the 'hvp' activity with course module id '278'."
}, {
    "Component": "System",
    "EventName": "Course viewed",
    "Description": "The user with id '2253' viewed the course with id '13'."
},{
    "Component": "Quiz",
    "EventName": "Quiz attempt viewed",
    "Description": "The user with id '2184' has viewed the attempt with id '1900' belonging to the user with id '2184' for the quiz with course module id '228'."
 }]
```

Comment: The answer to the question is "yes, you can". You need to implement it and it shouldn't be too hard. Did you try seomthing else than just declaring a string?

Comment: So you know the input is in the form of `"The user with id '{id1}' helped the user '{id2}' (rest irrelevant)"`. So you can parse this. What have you tried to do so?

Comment: @ThomasWeller  i have updated my code.

Comment: @CodeCaster the id i need is `@"The user with id '{userid}' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '{itemid}' with the quantity of '1'.";` rest other are irrelevant

Comment: Thanks. I think Regex is quite a good start here. You don't use the `StashAcquired` variable in your code yet, neither the other form with {userid} and {itemid}. Which of them shall actually be used? Or are you free to choose whatever you need?

Comment: i actually need to parse {userid} and {itemid} in any way. I am free to choose...but I want some generic way of doing that...because the input are not always the same. 
some time..input comes as `{userid} and {itemid}` or sometime as `{userid} and {moduleid}`. Input will be in an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for providing all the necessary information. Next time, please provide all information upfront. That will make your question less likely to attract negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the keywords are "user" along with "id" and "item" also with "id". The regex should reflect that, e.g.

```
user.*id.*'(?<userid>.*)'.*item.*id.*'(?<itemid>.*)'
```

Then, I see that sometimes you need "item", but sometimes "course" or "module". Let's add a choice `(...|...|...)` to that Regex:

```
user.*id.*'(?<userid>.*)'.*(item|module|course).*id.*'(?<itemid>.*)'
```

Unfortunately, that will add a new group, which you likely don't want. Let's make it non-capturing with `?:`:

```
user.*id.*'(?<userid>.*)'.*(?:item|module|course).*id.*'(?<itemid>.*)'
```

Now, this still fails for the text

```
"The user with id '2253' viewed the 'hvp' activity with course module id '278'"
```

because it has two apostrophes after "user" and "id. You want the `.*` to be less greedy, so change it to `.*?`:

```
user.*id.*?'(?<userid>.*?)'.*(?:item|module|course).*id.*'(?<itemid>.*)'
```

See also [all tests on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XLXHa4/1).

The code:

```
var s = "The user with id '2156' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '1' with the quantity of '1'";
var pattern = "user.*id.*?'(?<userid>.*?)'.*(?:item|module|course).*id.*'(?<itemid>.*)'";
var rex = new Regex(pattern);
var m = rex.Matches(s);
Console.WriteLine(m[0].Groups["userid"].Value + " " +  m[0].Groups["itemid"].Value);
```

Pro tip when working with Regex: use [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/). It has a very powerful output replacement for `Console.WriteLine()`. It can do stuff like:

[image: Regex in Linqpad]

That way, you don't need to code everything yourself. Instead you can just have a look at an object as a table.

Comment: if in case i need everything that is inside the `apostrophes`? like in case:
"The user with id '2253' viewed the 'hvp' activity with course module id '278'" I need all three...that is `userid`, `activity` and `moduleid`

Comment: @AakashBashyal: Please don't extend the question bit by bit. You asked for three things: courseid, moduleid and itemid. Now you want activityid as well. I feel like next week I have developed a whole application for you. Get the example up and running, understand it, do some experiments, try to fix the next problem yourself and if not possible within the next 3 hours, ask  another question.

Comment: @AakashBashyal: this answer should help you for the additional task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593191/regex-how-to-capture-optional-group-in-middle-of-text

Answer (score 0):

This approach might work: Split the string with `'` as delimeter. Then your user id is the 2nd part of the string, the item id 6th part of your string. This will result in the following code:

```
string input = "The user with id '2156' helped the user '2156' to acquire an item with the id '1' with the quantity of '1'.";
string[] parts = input.Split('\'');
string rawUserId = parts[1];
string rawItemId = parts[5];
int userId = int.Parse(rawUserId);
int itemId = int.Parse(rawItemId);
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wnDyWL

Comment: @AakashBashyal That shouldn't be a big deal. Just look at your EventName to see how you have to parse your string: `switch(EventName) { case "An Item Acquired":  ParseItemAquiredString(); break; case "Course module viewed": ParseCourseModuleString(); break; ...` It shouldn't be hard to transfer the above solution to the other string formats.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you, using **Regex**, :

```
    public static int GetIDFromString(string text, string partName)
    {
        var matchUserPart = Regex.Match(text, @$"{partName}(.*?)id(.*?)\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
        return matchUserPart.Length > 0 ? int.Parse(Regex.Replace(matchUserPart, @"\D", "")) : 0;
    }
```

You can just use it in this way:

```
        int userID = GetIDFromString(text, "user");
        int itemID = GetIDFromString(text, "item");
```

Note that **Regex** class is in **System.Text.RegularExpressions** namespace.

In **Regex**, **\d** (lower case) is used for every digits and vice versa **\D** (upper case) stands for every **not** digits in **Pattern** of Regex and **?** mark in **(.*?)** cause **Regex** to match first occurrence (turn off greedy in regex).

Comment: `user with id` phrase occurs 2 times sometimes in some cases. how to do in that case? Stuck with regex. Like in this situation: `"Description": "The user with id '2184' has viewed the attempt with id '1900' belonging to the user with id '2184' for the quiz with course module id '228'."`

Comment: Used  '(.*?)' pattern that turn off eager mode of regex which cause it to match the first occurrence in the  your text. It won't stuck there.

Comment: can you help me with the working code for that example?

Comment: This is a working code with your sample text [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BymkOG)